# A French Phrase Similar to "Expertise"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, loanwords, french

I am looking for a phrase that is used occasionally in English as a **near** synonym of "expertise". For some reason, "coup d'mentarie" keeps going through my mind, but I don't believe this actually means anything at all and it doesn't produce any results on the web.

To clarify, I am looking for a word or phrase that sounds similar to this, whilst I am foggy about the language of origin and precise meaning. French is just a guess. :)

Comment: Are you thinking of _coup de grâce? It does not fit your description (hence the comment) but might be what you have stuck in your mind.

Comment: Were you thinking of [*"coup de maître"*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coup-de-maître?q=coup+de+maitre)? It means *"masterstroke"*, so not quite expertise, but a vaguely similar idea.

Comment: By the way, you do realize that [_expertise_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=expertise&allowed_in_frame=0) itself is French right?

Comment: Yes, Peter Shor! "Coup de maître" is the phrase I've been trying to recall! How do I select your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: Tagger: I write it as an answer, and you select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you thinking of ["coup de maître"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coup-de-ma%C3%AEtre?q=coup+de+maitre)? It's usual translation is *"masterstroke"* (there's a website I found which shows it has also been translated as *"hole in one"* and *"home run"*, both used metaphorically), so it's not quite expertise, but it's a vaguely similar concept.

Comment: This may be the phrase you had in mind, but it in no way fits with your question. A better example might have been "Playing the Bartók Solo Sonata flawlessly was George's coupe de maître." And a coup is more suggestive of a singular event or milestone, and not an attribute, such as expertise might be.

Comment: @Jim Agreed. Which is why I added the clarification at the end of my question "I am foggy about the language of origin and precise meaning". I presented the way that I tended to use it in my head, while acknowledging that the actual phrase may be slightly different. My example is misleading, admittedly, and again that stems from my uncertainty over what the precise term was that I was trying to recollect. I'll remove it to make things clearer for others.

Answer (score 16):

> *Playing violin is George's [**forte**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forte)*
>
> a person's strong suit, or most highly developed characteristic, talent, or skill;
> something that one excels in.

---

[Etymologically,](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=forte)

> 1640s, from French *fort* "strong point (of a sword blade)," also *fort,* from Middle French *fort*.
> Meaning "strong point of a person" is from 1680s.
> Final -e- added 18c. in imitation of Italian *forte* "strong."

So don't let anyone tell you it's "Italian". It's French.

Comment: My bad. I concede that the noun form is French.

Comment: @bib is there a non-noun form of forte?

Comment: @TylerH Yes.  See the [first entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=forte&searchmode=none), an adjectival form. It can also be used adverbially.

Comment: @bib Hmm, I always just used that form as if it were a noun-type of music, similar to genre.

Comment: @bib: haha - I would say the "adjectival" musical instruction ***is*** "Italian"! To my mind it's not the same word at all as the one I posted up as an answer to OP's context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. That's why I deleted my first comment.

Comment: @bib: But it *was* an "apposite" comment, and I must admit it's only because I happen to know French reasonably well (and next to nothing of Italian) that I even thought it was worth hoping the "strong point" sense essentially derived from French. I do the Guardian crossword every day, and I reckon at least once a week they use the cue-word "loud" or similar to designate the letter(s) "f (ff)". And that I *know* is Italian, as practically all musical instructions are. Whatever - I'll keep the final line in the answer (but you personally are no longer "in the firing line", obviously! :)

Answer (score 8):

You might be looking for the phrase "**savoir-faire**" also.

In English, it mainly means **know-how** (knowing how to do) but it connotes a knowledge that comes from an expertise as well.

From [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/savoir-faire):

> The nearest English equivalent of savoir-faire is know-how. But while know-how pertains to nearly all skills, especially practical ones, savoir-faire usually refers specifically to skill in social and diplomatic situations.

Reference to expertise makes more sense in French though.

From the book "Knowledge, Skills and Competence in the European Labour Market"
*By Michaela Brockmann, Linda Clarke, Christopher Winch*:

[image: "Savoir-faire" based on the implementation in a concrete situation of both knowledge and experience (such as the blue-collar worker's manual dexterity, the skilled woker's ability to deal with breakdowns or malfunctions). This 'empirical' "savoir-faire" may be acquire both through leanring and through professional practice.]

[image: Practical knowledge or expertise. French: "savoir-faire: compétence, expérience" in the exercise of an activity.]

Comment: Good point and well brought up: +1. I don't think it can be fitted into the OP's sentence though.

Answer (score 0):

**[finesse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/finesse)** might fit also.

> *[mass noun]* Impressive delicacy and skill: *orchestral playing of great finesse*

[Etymology:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=finesse)

> 1520s, from Middle French finesse "fineness, subtlety," from Old French fin "subtle, delicate"

It is mentioned as the synonym of expertise in some of the sources as well.

Comment: It might be a *related* word, but I don't think anyone would accept *"Playing violin is George's finesse"*. Saying *finesse* is a synonym of *expertise* seems like a bit of a stretch to me.

Comment: @Fumble: I upvoted your answer. forte seems like a better choice. I just wanted to give an alternative answer. Though, you can fit this word to the context as well.

Comment: Yeah, you can certainly say things like *"George's violin playing shows great finesse"*. I must admit I feel slightly less comfortable with *"George has great finesse on the violin"* though. I think because I normally associate the word with a *performance*, rather than a *performer*. That's why I don't think it could easily be an "attribute" of George's exemplified by his violin playing - it's more an attribute of his violin playing (when he's on form).